# Moment.js - find previous range based on current range of date

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm using a plugin for Moment.js - [moment-range](https://github.com/gf3/moment-range)

Is it possible to get a previous range of dates based on a current date range. For example I have below scenario:

```
var currentStart = new Date(2014,11,01);
var currentEnd = new Date(2015,10,01);
```

The range above is **11months**, now we need the previous 11months which in this case will be:

```
var previousStart = new Date(2013,11,01);
var previousEnd = new Date(2014,10,01);
```

I'm not sure what is the best way to calculate the previous range of months or if there is an easier way to handle date ranges.

Any ideas!?

Comment: So then, October 2nd is not in either range?   And how are you using moment or moment-range? You are just showing `Date` objects here.

Comment: Also, you need to show what you have *tried* already.  Just stating your requirements is not sufficient. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1):

this is previouse range based on current range of what ever date you set:

```
var dateStart = "01-01-2021";
var dateEnd   = "01-31-2021";
// calcule date diff between two date
var diffDays = (Math.ceil((Math.abs(new Date(dateEnd) - new Date(dateStart)))/ (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))) + 1;
    
    
// Get Previous Date Start (Needed for Percent)
var previousStart.setDate(new Date(dateStart).getDate() - diifDaysFinale);
    
// Get Previous Date End (Needed for Percent)
var previousEnd.setDate(new Date(previousDateStart).getDate() + (diffDays-1));
    
console.log("previousStart: ",previousStart);
console.log("previousEnd: ",previousEnd);
```

Or By Using moment:

```
var previousStart = moment(dateStart).subtract(moment(dateEnd).diff(moment(dateStart), 'days') + 1,'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var previousEnd = moment(dateStart).subtract(1,'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```